# clojure (println "sometxt")

Tags: webbrowser, clojure

Kак вывести строку в `clojure` с помощью `(println "sometxt")` в браузер, без библиотеки `hiccup` к примеру? Что-то не пойму.

Comment: А где вы выполняете Clojure? Отвечаете им на запрос какой-то? И у вас точно не ClojureScript? Пока что вопросов больше, чем ответов.

Comment: ..все банально server ring  и решил ,как во многих языках через принт ,что нибудь  вывести и..  что то не получилось ..в репле без проблем ,а в браузер не получается ,и да это clojure ,а не clojureScript

Comment: Во многих это в каких? В PHP? Clojure всё-таки не времён CGI. А у Ring есть [страница Getting Started](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/Getting-Started), вы хотя бы её читали? UPD: возможно, я звучу немного едко, но меня правда удивляет, что вместо того, чтобы ознакомиться с тем, что вообще такое Ring, прежде чем начинать с ним работать, вы обратились на StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

В сущности, деятельность любого веб-приложения сводится к тому, чтобы сформировать в ответ на запрос от клиента собственный ответ и вывести его. Как именно это происходит в программном коде, зависит от способа взаимодействия с вебсервером:

- Если его нет (т. е. приложение само по себе вебсервер), вы отправляете по TCP-соединению сначала HTTP-статус с заголовками, потом пустую строку, а потом тело ответа.
- В CGI вы получаете тело запроса в stdin, а пишете в stdout самыми обычными printf/println'ами, теми же, которыми почти на любом языке пишется Hello World.
- А есть интерфейсы вроде Rack и Ring, в которых вы отвечаете клиенту, возвращая откуда-то какое-то одно значение, представляющее собой весь ответ.

---

**[Ring](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring)** — интерфейс, в котором веб-приложение представляет собой **функцию-обработчик** (handler), которая (в простейшем случае) принимает запрос и возвращает ответ.

Чтобы вывести `"sometext"` в браузер, вам даже `println` не нужен. С точки зрения HTTP (по которому веб-приложения, собственно, работают), вам нужно вернуть HTTP-ответ с **телом** (body) `"sometext"`. Кроме этого, неплохо бы обозначить, что это просто текст соответствующим **заголовком** (header): `Content-Type: text/plain`. Значение, представляющее в Ring такой ответ, может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
{:status 200
 :headers {"Content-Type" "text/plain"}
 :body "sometext"}
```

Остаётся только сделать функцию, возвращающую такой ответ:

```
(defn handler [request]
  {:status 200
   :headers {"Content-Type" "text/plain"}
   :body "sometext"})
```

Всё. Вот обработчик, выводящий `sometext`.

---

Из спортивного интереса использовать `println` тоже можно, конечно. Поможет [макрос `clojure.core/with-out-str`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-out-str), который подменяет stdout потоком, выводящим данные в строку-буфер, а полученную строку возвращает.

Выйдет примерно то же самое, что и в вышеприведённом обработчике, только `"sometext"` заменится на:

```
(with-out-str
  (println "sometext"))
```

То есть, как видите, можно, но зачем?

Comment: Спасибо (with-out-str) ,его и искал.

Comment: @Verve вы только будьте готовы, что Clojure, со склонностью к иммутабельностям и изоляции побочных эффектов, будет сопротивляться подобному коду. 